# How to color numbers in a vector by magnitude?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, colors

TL;DR: Trying to color console outputs in gradient values. I want to color elements in a vector according to their magnitudes and negativeness/positiveness.

I want to test output that will display ColumnA, ColumnB next to each other as a "table" (something I need to do using nothing more sophisticated than iomanip), but I want entries in columnB to be colored by their relative magnitudes (most negative-->bright red, most positive --> bright blue). If it is illegible against the black background, I would be happy with highlights. I suspect (but hope not) that I might have to install another libray?

I am just starting, so I want to test coloring vector elements with a simple example first.

Minimum working example:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//test these arrays first:
vector<int> columnA{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
vector<int> columnB{ -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5 };

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        cout << columnA[i] << "   " << columnB[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which OS, because in Linux this could be achieved by just using terminal control sequences.

Comment: There's really two parts to your question:  determining the color, and passing that color for use by the console UI.  You appear to be running on Windows; the available colors in the console is very limited.

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 OS. I am open to making adjustments if I have to, this is for an intro C++ class so I am trying to curb my ambitions while still being creative. I am open to making adjustments, I just think that coloring the values will make it more apparent to users how much entries vary by. I have 50 data points that will be compared in each row, so I need at least 50 [color] values (adjacent color values will be imperceptible and that is ok). What is the minimum workaround?